# FIWARE Cygnus can't persist in HDFSink

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus, webhdfs

I want to persist information in Hadoop through Cygnus.
I'm testing the services, but in Cygnus log I receive this:

```
msg=org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies[129] : Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth="u=hduser&p=hduser&t=simple&e=1535600601906&s=PBVO9ijLyamz6JCcTEohe76tgl0="; Path=/; Expires=jue, 30-ago-2018 03:43:21 GMT; HttpOnly". Unable to parse expires attribute: jue, 30-ago-2018 03:43:21 GMT

    [NGSIRestHandler] Bad HTTP notification (GET method not supported)
time=2018-08-29T17:53:25.008Z | lvl=WARN | corr=50e71d08-183d-4181-835a-09c5935adec4 | trans=50e71d08-183d-4181-835a-09c5935adec4 | srv=user_activity | subsrv=/user_activity | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=doPost | msg=org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource$FlumeHTTPServlet[192] : Deserializer threw unexpected exception. 
org.apache.http.MethodNotSupportedException: GET method not supported
```

But in the console, I receive that everything is ok.

My notification.sh is like that:

```
!/bin/sh    
URL=$1

if [ "$2" != "" ]
then
       SERVICE=$2
   else
          SERVICE=default
      fi

  if [ "$3" != "" ]
  then
         SERVICE_PATH=$3
 else
        SERVICE_PATH=/
    fi

    curl $URL -v -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'User-Agent: orion/0.10.0' --header "Fiware-Service: $SERVICE" --header "Fiware-ServicePath: $SERVICE_PATH" -d @- <<EOF
{
            "subscriptionId": "51c0ac9ed714fb3b37d7d5a8",
            "originator": "localhost",
            "contextResponses": [{
                "contextElement": {
                    "attributes": [{
                        "name": "temperature",
                        "type": "centigrade",
                        "value": "26.5"
                    }],
                    "type": "Room",
                    "isPattern": "false",
                    "id": "Room1"
                },
                "statusCode": {
                    "code": "200",
                    "reasonPhrase": "OK"
                }
            }]
        }
EOF
```

The NGSI is not supposed to be intended to receive HTTP notifications as it is a REST API?

Can anyone help me? It's my first time using this kind of services and I am absolutely lost.

For more information, I am using Cygnus version 1.6.0.

Thank you.

Comment: can you try with POST method? 'curl $URL --request POST'

Comment: I just test it @SaravananElumalai, but it doesn't work... I receive the same log.

Comment: Hi, can you provide more information?, the agent conf file and the full curl command sent to Cygnus?